# How to fix the headers of my table so they do not scroll

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, fixed-header-tables

I am trying to fix the header of my table so that it does not scroll but stays fixed in place.

I have searched some older SO threads to try and find a solution to fixing the header of a scrollable table.  I'm rather new to bootstrap and React and I believe I am close.  I am asking this question here to find an answer specific to my code.

my table in a react component

```
    <div>
      <div className="tablediv">
      <div className="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">
        <table className="table table-hover table-striped table-light">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Value: USD</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {priceAndDateArray.slice(0).reverse().map((item, i) => (
              <tr key={i}>
                <th scope="row">{i+1}</th>
                <td>{item.date}</td>
                <td>{item.price}</td>
              </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

my css relevant to the table

```
.tablediv {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 5%;
  justify-content: center
}

.tablediv tr {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

.my-custom-scrollbar {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.table-wrapper-scroll-y {
  display: block;
}
```

Expected results is the top header of the table (#, Date, Value: USD) to be fixed in place.  Actual results are that they scroll with the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this.

```
.tablediv {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: space-evenly;
    padding: 5%;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: That didnt work unfortunately, it had a pretty funny effect though.

Answer (score 0):

you want `css position:sticky` This will hold the header until the content scrolls past. Here's [info and examples](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/)

Roughly though your css would look like this

```
thead {
 position: sticky;
 top:0; //or whatever offset you want
 z-index: 100; // make sure it stacks higher than other stuff on the page
}
```